# Elasticsearch efficient index management

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch in a non-typical way and would like opinions about how efficient this is.

I create and entire set of "docs" with several fields each. I do this in Spark as an RDD of Map[String, Any]. Then I overwrite the index every so often with potentially new data. I suspect the more typical way is to update or add a doc at a time. I do this using the Elasticsearch Spark Scala support with:

```
val docsRDD: RDD[Map[String, Any]] = getDocs()
docsRDD.saveToEs(esIndexURI, Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))
```

I've done this in two workflows and want to know the trade-offs for them

1. **Delete** index, **create** it, **write** it, then **refresh** to get the index made available. This is because as I understand it the index is not really deleted until the refresh, which will do something like a hot-swap of new index for the old. In other words Elasticsearch works away in the background then swaps in the new fresh index at refresh time.
2. **Overwrite** the index in place with the Spark code with no delete/create/refresh.

At first I was updating documents in place but that proved impractical and the Spark support seemed to suggest the all-at-once writing method. Both seem to work but I have a small dataset now and wonder how the different approaches (or other suggestions) affect:

- Query performance during the operations
- Speed of reindex
- Coherence of the index. Is #2 creating an index with partial updates so queries will be against an incomplete update? Is #1 causing the index to be unavailable for some length of time?

Answer (score 0):

A third option: first assign an alias to the current index and address searches through that alias rather than directly to the index.  When updating/rebuilding your index, write a brand new index with the most current data, don't overwrite or delete/rebuild the current one.  When the new index has been built, assign the alias to it and remove it from the older one.  Once the alias has been assigned to your updated index, delete/archive/whatever the old index. Repeat as needed for subsequent index rebuilds.

Accomplishes exactly what you need, doesn't interfere with reads on the current index version while the new one is building and doesn't rely on timing/luck to keep a deleted index momentarily searchable. It does require you have sufficient storage space for two versions of your index, of course.

Comment: Understood, but my understanding was that the refresh committed the previous operations and in effect did the same as the alias trick with #1. Is this wrong? BTW this will eventually be with a 3 machine cluster with multiple masters and index replication, if that matters.